# What is difference between Bootstrap, Twitter Bootstrap, and Bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can someone let me know what is the difference between Bootstrap, Twitter Bootstrap and Bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

In the context of CSS frameworks, Bootstrap and Twitter Bootstrap are the same thing.

Bootstrap 3 is the third major version of Twitter Bootstrap. (When this question was asked, it had not been released yet.)

(There's another unrelated definition: to *bootstrap* a computer program or system can refer to running certain phases of early startup. It's often abbreviated as "booting", as in "booting up a computer". [Wikipedia has an extensive definition and etymology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping#Applications) which I won't reproduce here.)

Comment: The `bootstrap` tag on SO defines another meaning of "Bootstrap" - "A bootstrap is a series of procedures run when an application starts up or a request over the web is received. For questions about Twitter's Bootstrap CSS framework, please use the twitter-bootstrap tag"

Comment: Thanks duskwuff, if it is up since July 2013 how come there is the  2.3.2 still on the website then?

Comment: @MonaCoder: That's not what I meant - I mean, right now, 2.3.2 is the current version, and Bootstrap 3 is not out yet. That will surely change, though, so I was adding the date for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: Looks like the Bootstrap 3 release date is Aug 19 - http://blog.getbootstrap.com/. You can preview 3 now at http://www.bootply.com

Comment: So Bootstrap 3 has been out for a while now - and its now the official version. 2.3.2 has been deprecated for about the same amount of time as well.

Answer (score 8):

There's no difference. Twitter Bootstrap was the official name for version 1.0 (Twitter Bootstrap). Later the name has been shortened.

Answer (score 7):

As Bootstrap came from the 2 famous guys at Twitter, hence sometimes it's called Twitter Bootstrap. Bootstrap 3 is the latest version.(I guess version 4 is on its way).

An excerpt from Wikipedia:

> Bootstrap, originally named Twitter Blueprint, was developed by Mark Otto and Jacob Thornton at Twitter as a framework to encourage consistency across internal tools. Before Bootstrap, various libraries were used for interface development, which led to inconsistencies and a high maintenance burden.

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap that you have tagged has a description A bootstrap is a series of procedures run when an application starts up or a request over the web is received.

Comment: How does it explain differences between Bootstrap, Twitter Bootstrap and Bootstrap 3?