# Twitter Bootstrap VS Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I need to understand better about bootstrap
What is the different between bootstrap and twitter bootstrap?

Any cons and pros?

Comment: If you don't provide a link to the "bootstrap" you are referring to, i suppose you mean the same thing. People tend to say "bootstrap" to say twitter bootstrap faster.

Comment: Actually there's no difference at all. They're just one `CSS` framework by Twitter. And @nozzleman is right people say `bootstrap` just to say it faster. But yes it depends on what **bootstrap** you are refering to.

Comment: Just read the wiki of the tag : Twitter Bootstrap is a front-end framework from Twitter designed to kick-start development of Web apps and sites. Use "twitter-bootstrap" and NOT "bootstrap" to ask a question about this framework.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is difference between BootStrap, Twitter BootStrap, and BootStrap 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710862/what-is-difference-between-bootstrap-twitter-bootstrap-and-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 5):

**[Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)** is a frontend framework which contains mostly used, reusable CSS and JS components so you need not reinvent the wheel.

**Bootstrap** that you have tagged has a description `A bootstrap is a series of procedures run when an application starts up or a request over the web is received.`

Both are not even close to each other. They are completely different.

Comment: What context is it recommended to use bootstrap or twitter bootstrap?

Comment: If you need to develop the frontend of the website, you can use Twitter Bootstrap.

The other bootstrap is a term associated to "speed up"

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking Bootstrap just in Bootstrap framework (https://getbootstrap.com), as I believe the author was clearly in HTML & CSS context, following title, description and mentioned tag (`twitter-bootstrap`).

I googled by "Twitter Bootstrap" and the home page of the project is https://getbootstrap.com/2.0.2/index.html

Bootstrap and Twitter Bootstrap "are the same thing". The difference between them is the version of the "Bootstrap HTML,CSS (optionally JS) Framework".

Following the description of `twitter-bootstrap` StackOvreflow tag (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) we have the following description:

> Bootstrap is a front-end framework designed to kick-start development of Web apps and sites. For questions related to a version of Bootstrap also use the specific version's tag from "twitter-bootstrap-2", "twitter-bootstrap-3" and "bootstrap-4" tags.

From wikipedia ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_(front-end_framework) )

In History >> Early beginnings:

> Bootstrap, originally named Twitter Blueprint, was developed by Mark Otto and Jacob Thornton at Twitter as a framework to encourage consistency across internal tools.

ending with this:

> (...)It was renamed from Twitter Blueprint to Bootstrap, and released as an open source project on August 19, 2011.

Then, my conclusion is that along the lifetime of the project, it received more than only one name making this confusion.

Answer (score -2):

It's one and same just a bit here and there. It totally depends on you which one you use many people go with Twitter Bootstrap as the CSS jQuery and  effects are good. But you can achieve same with the Bootstrap also